# Make a fullscreen responsive slider by deleting div container?

Tags: slider, overriding, fullscreen

thanks for helping:

here is my objectif: make Make a fullscreen responsive slider on a homepage with joomla:

the main problem my template's slider position is in multiple container just like these

```html
<div>
    <div id="ja-slider" class="wrap ">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="main-inner1 clearfix">
                <div class="ja-moduletable ;Position: slider" id="Mod104">
                    <div class="moduletable-inner clearfix">
                        <div class="ja-box-ct clearfix">        
                            <div id="slider" class="favslider">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

what I wish is:

```html
<div>
    <div id="ja-slider" class="wrap ">
        <div id="slider" class="favslider">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

is there anyone could help? thanks a lots! I'm not a programmer but I understand html and CSS.

thanks again! hoping this thread could helps others!

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to override the existing code using an extension like ReReplacer or similar:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/replace/4336